# Running pipelines with data parallellization

Tags: kedro

I've been running the kedro tutorials (the hello world and the spaceflight) and I'm wondering if it's easily possible to do data parallelization using Kedro.
Imagine, the situation where I have a node that needs to be executed in millions of files.

I've seem that there's the option `kedro run -p`, but this do only task parallelization (as stated here https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/03_tutorial/04_create_pipelines.html).

Thanks for the any feedback

Comment: I am running into a similar issue.  I have a single node that take in many datasets and unions them. It would be nice if kedro could lazy load all inputs in the background then continue when they all resolve.

Answer (score 3):

Kedro has a number of build-in DataSet classes. For IO parallelization, there is SparkDataSet which delegates IO parallelization to PySpark https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/04_user_guide/09_pyspark.html#creating-a-sparkdataset

Another dataset is DaskDataSet, but this is still WIP in this PR https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/pull/97 (if you want to use Dask, you could have a look at this PR and [create your own custom dataset](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/03_tutorial/03_set_up_data.html#creating-custom-datasets))